# Firefox and Chrome stops displaying my sprite after 655 images

Tags: php, html, css, sprite, css-sprites

### the problem

Hi, i'm working with sprites and got some interesting behavior of firefox and Chrome. When my sprite have **655** images or less, my sprite works fine. But when it goes furter (656 or more) it doesn't get displayed (just become invisible). I'm guessing the problem is not in my code since it works fine in Opera and IE. How come?

---

### details

I'm using PHP to generate the sprites on-the-fly. The generated html goes like this:

```
<span class="_sprite_images _sprite_images_1"></span>
<span class="_sprite_images _sprite_images_0"></span>
<span class="_sprite_images _sprite_images_2"></span>
<span class="_sprite_images _sprite_images_3"></span>
<span class="_sprite_images _sprite_images_4"></span>
<span class="_sprite_images _sprite_images_5"></span>

[...]
```

and the CSS looks like this:

```
._sprite_images{background:url("../sprite_images/sprite.jpg");display:inline-block;}

._sprite_images_0{width:50px;height:50px;background-position:0 0px;}
._sprite_images_1{width:50px;height:50px;background-position:0 -50px;}
._sprite_images_2{width:50px;height:50px;background-position:0 -100px;}

[...]
```

Each image of my sprites have the size 50x50 (px) and are about 2 to 6 KB.
I have tested them with the types jpg, png and gif. All got the same results.

---

### screenshots

655 images

[image: 655 images]

656 images

[image]

Comment: Can you take a screen shot of what you are trying to accomplish?  Perhaps we can suggest an alternative method that would be less demanding of the browser?

Comment: well, what i need is actually the information (it's for a paper work -and self curiosity, of course). just added the screenshots.

Comment: can you show an example in http://jsfiddle.net/ for better understanding the problem.

Comment: I see you have many open tabs and software, and active plugin, maybe a memory problem?

Comment: This is a guess, but by your description and since you're having all images next to each other on the horizontal, you might maybe hit some browser limit (your image is 32.750px wide, to my calculation). A way to confirm this, would be to spread the images evenly over the horizontal and vertical. E.g. break after every 25th image. If I'm right, you should be able to fit *a lot* more images.

Comment: @MatTheCat it's not the memory | @polarblau i tried to break after every 100th image putting this in the loop `if($i % 100 == 99) echo '<br />';`. still didn't work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Edit:** If the cause of the issue is not the CSS length integer value, then it's the maximum image size the browser(s) in question can process. This probably is more the case here re-reading your question.

See [Firefox Bug 591822: Images taller or wider than 32767](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=591822)

I used the value calculated below to look up that ticket quickly via google ;)

If you want it to work, help with [cairo, the underlying image library](http://cairographics.org/).

What you can do as well is to not spread your sprites on one axis (y in your case) only, but on both (x and y):

```
0: 0 0
...
654: 0 -32700
655: -50 0
```

and so on. PHP:

```
$offset = -50;
$x = (int)($n/655) * $offset;
$y = $n % 655 * $offset;
```

---

You have an offset of `-50` pixels per sprite.

The first sprite has an offset of `0` (`(1-1) * -50`).

For the sprite #655 the offset is `654 * -50` which is `-32,700`.

The sprite #656 has the offset `655 * -50` which is `-32,750`.

The sprite #657 has the offset `656 * -50` which is `-32,800`.

A 16 bit, unsigned [integer <sup>Wikipedia</sup>](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_%28computer_science%29) (halfword, word, short) ranges from `0` to `65535`, it's signed counterpart from `-32,768` to `32,767`.

Just comparing these values show, that if the browser in question uses that data-type to store the integer value of the pixel unit, it won't be able to:

```
-32,800 is lower than -32,768
```

What can happen in this case is, that it's getting a round-trip:

```
-32,800 => 32
```

If you would place a sprite on your sprite pane on the (relative) coordinate -32 (which is not possible), you might be able to see it.

This is only an assumption, I have not the source codes of the browsers in question checked, so take it with a grain of salt.

However this might lead to some quick solving strategy which is fair if it turns out working fast:

**How to solve?**

You can try (as long as the rendering algorithms are not affected by this), to use another unit. Put all your sprites into a parent element, e.g. a `<div>`:

```
<div class="sprites">
  <span class="img-1"></span>
  <span class="img-2"></span>
  <span class="img-3"></span>
  ...
  <span class="img-656"></span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.sprites {font-size:50px;}
    div.sprites span {background: ... ; height: 1em; width: 1em;} /* default sprite definition*/
        div.sprites span.img-1 {background-position:0 0;}
        div.sprites span.img-2 {background-position:0 -1em;}
        div.sprites span.img-3 {background-position:0 -2em;}
        ...
        div.sprites span.img-656 {background-position:0 -655em;}
```

This might be more cross-browser compatible, as the integer length of each unit is not much smaller.

Let me know if it works, you didn't post any code in your question as a demo example, so I didn't compile a demo as well, but I hope the idea behind the solution suggestion is clear.

Comment: but both Crhome and Firefox were able to display [this image](http://caamorim.files.wordpress.com/2011/02/fullmoon1.jpg) which is 8211 x 8652. i guess you were right about CSS in the first place - once i get confirmation i post it here. thank you (:

Comment: it seems like it's the CSS integer's fault indeed :p